# Selecting subset of columns from a datatable

Tags: c#

I have a dataset of 15 columns. I want to generate an excel sheet with only 4 columns of that dataset. How can we select a subset of columns in to a datatable?
Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: How are you trying to do it. It's so obvious I can't understand what problem are you finding.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505) - we would like to see your efforts.

Comment: I tried converting dataset to Enumerable and wrote a linq query to get few columns out of it. But through LINQ, I could only achive to get a list<T> of the values and not the datatable. I am now going to try approach provided by James.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `DefaultView.ToTable` for this:

```
var table = table.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Column1", "Column2", "Column3");
```

Here's the documentation: [DefaultView.ToTable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind the false stands for a boolean flag for "distinct". If enabled, it is equivalent to removing non-unique entries.

For a prod application, I would advise passing an array of column names instead to avoid hardcoding. You can use list.ToArray<string> or just make a string[] to meet the method requirements.